# How to SET have_query_cache = YES?

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I've tried to set this by using SET VARIABLE but it said that have_query_cache is read-only

```
mysql>SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
+------------------+-------+
|    Variable_name | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache |   YES |
+------------------+-------+
```

Comment: The query cache was removed in MySQL 8.0.3. `have_query_cache` is deprecated, always has a value of `NO`, and you should expect it to be removed in a future MySQL release. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_have_query_cache)

Comment: I need to allocate 32 MB of RAM for the query cache. How I can make it in MySQL 8.0?

Comment: You don't believe the User Manual which claims that the query cache is removed at all? You hope that's not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For supported versions of MySQL (less than 8.0 or so), you [enable the query cache in the server configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-configuration.html) using e.g. the variables `query_cache_size` and `query_cache_type`
.

The `have_query_cache` variable only informs you whether the cache is enabled at present.

Comment: Okay, now I got it. As I assume I have to set query_cache_type = 1, right?

Comment: Yes, and `query_cache_size` to 33554432 (32*1024*1024). But they won't do anything on MySQL 8+.